# Accelerometer: Detect lowest point of screen

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a algorithm that detects the lowest point of the screen using the accelerometer using Xcode and Objective-C. I want to draw a sprite that follows the outside of the screen and never crosses through the middle. Always gravitating to the bottom of the screen.

Below is what I have so far. This moves the sprite around fairly well, but still allows the sprite to go through the middle of the screen. I am averaging the last AVG_SIZE values to reduce the jitter. The commented section is my failed attempt at trying to force it to follow the perimeter of the screen. Any suggestions?

```
for(int i = 0; i < AVG_SIZE-1; i++){
    x_array[i] = x_array[i+1];
    y_array[i] = y_array[i+1];
}
float tempAccelerationX = acceleration.x;
float tempAccelerationY = acceleration.y;
/*if(fabsf(tempAccelerationX) > fabsf(tempAccelerationX)){
    if(tempAccelerationY > 0)
        tempAccelerationY = 1;
    else
        tempAccelerationY = -1;
}else if(fabsf(tempAccelerationX) < fabsf(tempAccelerationX)){
    if(tempAccelerationX > 0)
        tempAccelerationX = 1;
    else
        tempAccelerationX = -1;
}*/

x_array[AVG_SIZE-1] = ( (tempAccelerationY+1) / 2 );
y_array[AVG_SIZE-1] = 1- ( (tempAccelerationX+1) / 2 );
float ratio_x = 0;
float ratio_y = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < AVG_SIZE; i++){
    ratio_x += x_array[i];
    ratio_y += y_array[i];
}
ratio_x /= AVG_SIZE;
ratio_y /= AVG_SIZE;
[_sprite setPosition: ccp( self.contentSize.width*ratio_x, self.contentSize.height*ratio_y )];
```

Answer (score 0):

What about make your code easier? Look on [this](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/cocos2d-moving-sprites-with-the-accelerometer) code for accelerometer, especially on update method of this tutorial, it's make sprite don't fall off screen offsets.

Here:

```
 float imageWidthHalved = player.texture.contentSize.width * 0.5f; 
 float imageHeightHalved = player.texture.contentSize.height * 0.5f;

 float leftBorderLimit = imageWidthHalved; 
 float rightBorderLimit = screenSize.width - imageWidthHalved;
 float topBorderLimit = imageHeightHalved; 
 float bottomBorderLimit = screenSize.height - imageHeightHalved;
```

Just change limits for your needs and I think you get what you want.

Comment: This example does not meet my specification. I always want the sprite to be on the edge of the screen. Imagine a marble in a hallow transparent picture frame. As you rotate the frame, the marble always stays at the bottom. I want my sprite to be the marble as I rotate the device.